# Is it possible to enable or disable xmlHTTP object from Browser?

Tags: browser

In Mac OS, Fire fox Version 3.6.3 is blocking XMLHttp Object in one machine but it didn't block in same set of OS and browser versions in other machine. Is there any way to enable or disable xmlhttp from browser?

Answer (score 0):

XMLHttpRequest, like any other JavaScript interface, can be blocked in Firefox using [CAPS](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/components/ConfigPolicy.html) preferences (`capability.policy.default.XMLHttpRequest`).

But it's highly unlikely that this has been done. (There is no UI for it.) I suspect you have a different problem.